# Pros/Cons for horizontal or vertical cabin trollies

Tags: luggage

There are two types of trollies, ones that are more vertical and ones that are more horizontal:

[image]

Photos of both types can be seen at [horizontal trolley](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/1/1b/Berlin_hauptbahnhof_drei_rollkoffer_15.04.2011_15-07-46.JPG/320px-Berlin_hauptbahnhof_drei_rollkoffer_15.04.2011_15-07-46.JPG) and 
[vertical trolley](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/2/2d/Samsonite_Pro-DLX_4_Rolling_Tote_16.4_Inch_Black.jpg/337px-Samsonite_Pro-DLX_4_Rolling_Tote_16.4_Inch_Black.jpg).

I would like to know if in practice does it matter if a cabin trolley has it's wheels on the short or long site (of course assuming both have the same volume)? Is one geometry better than the other?

I could imagine that the horizontal one has a longer handle and the handle might be divided into more segments to fold it up. I could image this makes it more likely to break? Is this true?

Observing other passengers, it seems that the second type seems the high version seems to be more frequent and if the wide version occurs the owner seems to be male. I wonder if there are reasons for this.

Comment: I've seen a few females with horizontal trolleys, but only ones wearing signs of working for an airline. - There are many other factors involved in whether the handle of a trolley is likely to break,but my experience just from vertical trolleys of different size is that longer handles with more segements are more wobbly, it doesn't matter when you just pull the trolley, but if you stop and rest your hand on the handle you can feel it.

Comment: The ones I've seen, the things you're calling "horizontal" are much smaller: the same width as "vertical" ones but much shorter. They're not rotated but cut down. A very wide bag would be very annoying.

Answer (score 0):

When you need to use trolleys down narrow aisles, like in trains or planes, every extra inch width is an annoyance.
Those men you see using the lower, wider version likely travel mostly by car or taxi and when flying stay in the front end of the plane.